# Two equal-height **minipages** in Latex Beamer?

Tags: latex, beamer

I was looking for ways to have a side-by-side **minipages** on a Latex beamer.
I will be clear, this is not two columns or mult-column or whatever. I specifically need minipages.

To do so, I created a nice command/function which does it nicely, but I am trying to make the two miniapges always be equal in height as well.
Any suggestions on how to force them to be equal in size?
Also general improvement suggestions and tips are welcomed.

```
\def \MinSideBySideGap {0.02} % minimal Gap between left/right sides

\newcommand{\SideBySide}[3][0.5]
{
    %
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
        {\FPeval{\leftwidth}{0.5-\MinSideBySideGap/2}%
         \FPeval{\rightwidth}{\leftwidth}%
        }% if #1 is empty
        {\FPeval{\leftwidth}{min(#1-\MinSideBySideGap/2,1.0)}%
         \FPeval{\rightwidth}{max(1.0-\leftwidth-\MinSideBySideGap,0.0)}
        }% if #1 is not empty
    %
    % Left Part
    \begin{minipage}{\leftwidth\textwidth}
    #2
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    % Right Part    
    \begin{minipage}{\rightwidth\textwidth}
    #3
    \end{minipage}%
}
```

Towards @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz questions, this was the very old origin of this:

```
\newcommand{\SideBySide}[2]
{
\begin{columns}[T] % align columns
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
#1
\end{column}%
\hfill%
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
#2
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more background why the minipages should have the same height? You could use minipages with an explicit height setting if you know how tall they should be. Or you could use tcolorboxes with an equal height group. If this has something to do with alignment, I would use columns. They are really just minipages with some extra goodies.

Comment: I will consider the idea of tcolorboxes and see if it might be relevant, but this is secondary at this point.
At this setup, they adjust to the text itself, so this is dynamic and nice - I want to keep that aspect, but have them both equal in height at the same time (so both correspond in size to the largest).

Comment: Just to understand the problem: why do you want them to have the same height?

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to pre-specify the height (dynamically adjusted)

Comment: yes, but I would like to understand **why**, as this might influence what's the best strategy.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "why" part (I'm doing too many things at once). It's mostly a visual thing that works well with a bunch of other things that I already have, so that I don't have to redo a whole lot of slides. There are alot of slides where certain items are aligned on both sides in a dumb manual way and I don't like it. This is basically a way to improve things without causing too much issues with existing beamers. If you have 2 ways (or more) and feel like sharing them both, I will be willing to experiment with both - my approach is not the best around.

Comment: From your description, this still sounds like a job for beamer columns to me. Do you have a specific example in which columns would not work?

Comment: Not at this instance, I might get one later. But to clarify, originally this was based on columns and was changed at some point due to minipage being more practical... I added the really old legacy code that was there originally to the main post.

Comment: Don't use `\hfill` between columns, beamer will automatically distribute them. I also like to use the `onlytextwidth` option to get the same margins as in the surrounding frame.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... The original version was not made by me, it was just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't see a reason why you would need minipages of the same height, but just as a proof of concept, you could use tcoloboxes instead of minipages. They have the ability to form "equal height groups":

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{width=(\linewidth-4mm)/2,before=,after={},enhanced,interior empty,equal height group=\insertframenumber,frame hidden}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tcolorbox}%
  test
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{tcolorbox}%
  test
  
  test
  \end{tcolorbox}%
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

(for the image, I removed the `interior empty` option so one can see the height of the box)

Comment: Thank you. I will try and see if this doesn't create compatibility issues.